# Как работает личный ящик на Stack Overflow?

Tags: поддержка, личный-ящик

Не совсем понятна логика работы личного ящика. По идее, сообщения на почту мне должны приходить, если есть отклики на мои сообщения/комментарии, когда меня долго не было. Но почему-то могут прийти спустя 12 часов непосещения, а спустя неделю при этом - не приходят.

**Update 1**
В настройке стоит "Входящие сообщения - ежедневно".

Comment: Вероятно, стоит опираться на имеющиеся у Вас настройки, их хорошо бы внести в текст сообщения.

Comment: не менял. Даже не задумывался, т.е. по умолчанию. Сейчас полезу их искать :) Стоит "Ежедневно".